# MySql Stored Procedure number incrementer

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm attempting to build an account number generator. I was thinking I could accomplish this by building a stored procedure for incrementing numbers in a db table followed by returning the value.

I'm not a dba, so I do not know very much about setting something like this up. Could someone point me in the right direction in order to accomplish this task. Thanks.

Comment: You could just use [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-auto-increment.html)...

Comment: I agree with eggyal that MySQL Auto_Inrement is the way to go. I'm deleting my earlier "answer" which overlooked this. Thanks for the correction, eggyal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an Auto Increment Number column will resolve you problem.. and if your account number is alphanumeric then you can logically concat that incremented number with your string part. And yes, procedure is also an alternate, it will call purely your logic.